# mod to remove trailing slash is not taking effect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried several different mods on my htaccess file to remove the trailing slash from my urls. Nothing is working. Any idea why? I'm on a shared linux hostgator server.  Here's all the code in my htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP52 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php52/lib
</IfModule>

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to turn on the engine. Add this above the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Please read the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks Mike. I added that and still no improvement. I've tried other codes such as `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: I talked to hostgator and they said that mod_rewrite was enabled on the server, so I don't understand why those codes aren't working. :-/